# Making a form script responsive with css?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

we're using an SEO service though upcity.com which requires us to embed a form onto our website. What we're finding is that the form itself doesn't respond all that well on mobile, which really defeats the purpose of what we're trying to do. So I'm looking for any recommendations as to how to possibly modify the script either with CSS potentially or something else.

```
<script>
 embedConfig = {
   embedCode: '51ad0f6943ac934ccbd03059c4ae74c6546d7229',
   orientation: 'portrait',
   frameStyle: {
     border: '0px',
     width: '360px',
     height: '660px'
   }
 }
 </script>
 <script src="//upcity.com/javascripts/embed_report_card.js"></script>
```

I'm not sure if the script provides enough information, but I'm happy to add more info if needed. Thanks!

Comment: An image, code, jsfiddle all of those could be lovely

Comment: If you view the dom-rendered source, likely the frame has an ID of sorts attached to it.  You could then attach a media query to that frame's element with some JS (ie, .css() of jQuery).

Answer (score 0):

The form embed is likely contained in an iframe. If that's the case, you can set a max-width of 100% for the iframe inside your media query. However, you can't really apply styles to the content contained within the iframe, so its likely going to look sub par.

Comment: I appreciate the quick response. Unfortunelty, there isn't a media query setup for this particular script, and if we modify the width to 100% in replacement of the 360px, it doesn't actually do anything. The company itself has indicated they don't have a responsive solution to this yet, so we're trying to find a work around